# Python - lambda on pandas dataframe with nan rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, null, apply

I want to apply an alteration to a column of my dataframe where the cells are not empty. This is the dataframe that I am using:

```
df = pd.DataFrame ([{'name':None, 'client':None, 'fruit':'orange'},
                    {'name':'halley','client':'abana', 'fruit':'pear'},
                    {'name':'josh','client':'a', 'fruit':'apple'},
                    {'name':'kim','client':'b', 'fruit':'apple'}])
```

output:

```
   name    client fruit
0  nan     nan    orange
1  halley  abana  pear
2  josh    a      apple
3  kim     b      apple
```

I want to rename clients with string shorter than 5 characters to be 'client_x' instead and this is what I did:

```
df['client'] =df['client'].apply(lambda x: x if len(x)>5 else "client_"+x)
```

but I have witnessed the following two possible errors:

```
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

I don't understand how nan can be assumed as a float, but I would really like a smart way to get through this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) for working with missing values `NaN`s with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['client'] = np.where(df['client'].str.len()>=5, df['client'], "client_"+df['client'])
```

Comment: you had it in the wrong order ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str.len`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) to get the string length and feed it to [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) to replace the short names with their prepended variant. NaNs will be excluded by `str.len`:

```
df['long_name'] = df['client'].mask(df['client'].str.len().lt(5),
                                    'client_'+df['client'])
```

output:

```
     name client   fruit long_name
0    None   None  orange      None
1  halley  abana    pear     abana
2    josh      a   apple  client_a
3     kim      b   apple  client_b
```